# Are the <cstring> header and the <string> header the same?

Tags: c++, string, header, declaration, c-strings

I'm trying to use the `<string>` header file but I noticed that there's also the `<cstring>` header.

What is the difference between the two or are they the same?

Comment: no, not the same https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string

Comment: There is `<string>` (`std::string` etc.) and `<cstring>` (the C++ binding of the C string API with functions `std::strlen()`, `std::strcpy()`, etc.) These are two separate things.

Comment: You can open the files and look at how similar they are.

Comment: Most header beginning with `c` are to *port* C-headers into C++ ones (`<xxx.h>` -> `<cxxx>`).

Answer (score 6):

> Are `<cstring>` header and string header the same?

No, they are not the same.

> what is the difference between them

`<cstring>` is a C++ standard library header that wraps the C standard library header  `<string.h>`. It declares C standard functions such as `strlen()` in the C++ `std` namespace.

`<string>` is a C++ standard library header that defines the `std::string` class (among other things).

Answer (score 4):

The header `<string>` contains declarations related to the class template `std::basic_string`.

The header `<cstring>` refers to declarations in the C Standard header `<string.h>`

From the C++ 14 Standard (17.6.1.2 Headers)

> 4 Except as noted in Clauses 18 through 30 and Annex D, the contents
> of each header cname shall be the same as that of the corresponding
> header name.h, as specified in the C standard library (1.2) or the C
> Unicode TR, as appropriate, as if by inclusion. In the C++ standard
> library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined
> as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace
> std. It is unspecified whether these names are first declared within
> the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace std by
> explicit using-declarations (7.3.3).

The C declarations from the header `<string.h>` included in the header `<cstring>` have C language linkage.